# dlib installation on jupyter(Anaconda 3)

Tags: python, opencv, installation, jupyter-notebook, dlib

Can anyone tell that how much time it will take to install the 'dlib' library in jupyter.
I am trying from 2 days but its not installing.
Thanks.

I have used following command to install dlib in jupyter:
pip install dlib

Comment: Please tell us more information about the environment, such as what's the python version and system operation?

Answer (score 0):

Open powershell in anaconda. Create an environment using

```
conda create -n envname
```

and activate the environment via

```
conda activate envname
```

Then try this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

Comment: I am getting the following error while installing the dlib in jupyter:

Comment: Collecting dlib
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000185913D9288>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/dlib/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by